# Ajax envia consulta php em Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Olá amigos estou estudando Ajax estou tentando fazer essa execução de código funcionar, mas ainda não consegui.
Estou tentando fazer após formulário`produtos` ser selecionador é enviado para `consultarcor.php` via Ajax as informações para consultar as cores de cada produto selecionado `consultarcor.php` verifica e o resultado devolvido para`cores` como `<option>` para seleção em outro formulário.

Alguém pode verificar o que cometi de errado pois o Ajax não funciona.

```
 function showHint(str) {
   if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("produto").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var vasr="cor="; 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("produto").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "consultacor.php"+str, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(vasr);
```

Formulario Html

```
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2"name="quant" placeholder="Quant." onkeypress="return maskKeyPress(event)"/></td>
     <td><input list='produtos' name='produto' onchange="showHint()"/>
     <datalist id='produtos'><?php
      $sql= mysqli_query($conn,"select DISTINCT descricao from produtos  order by descricao");
      while ($resp = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

     $group=$resp['descricao'];
      echo "
```

";
          }

```
      ?> </datalist></td>
      <td>
      <input list='cor' name='cor'/>

      </td>
      </tr>
```

Codigos dentro de consultacor.php

```
    <?php
    include "conecta.inc";
    $q[]= $_POST['produto'];
    $q = array_filter($q);

    $query.= "select * from produtos where descricao='$q'";

    $x = mysqli_query($conn,$query );

    while($prt=mysqli_fetch_array($x)){ 
    $cor[]=$prt['cores'];   

    echo "
    <datalist id='cores'>
    <option value='$cor'>
    </datalist>";
     }
     ?>
```

Este é o erro apresentado "console"

ficha.php:110 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Olha no console do navegador, para ver qual erro é

Comment: não apresenta o erro apenas não executa a consulta.

Comment: muda `$query.= "select * from produtos where descricao='$q'";` por `$query = "select * from produtos where descricao='$q'";`

Comment: vc chegou ver se existe algum valor em `$_POST`, da um `print_r()`nele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quantidade de incoerências no código é grande.

No HTML não existe um elemento cujo id seja **produto**, você esta usando a tag `getElementbyId` para pegar uma id que não existe ao longo do código, e analisando o mesmo, você deveria usar `getElementsByName("produtos")`, assim, para tentar recuperar o valor do teu produto selecionado e então seguir adiante.

Já no PHP, o `<datalist id="cores">` não equivale ao `<input list="cor" />` seguido disso, imagino que o *while* iria imprimir muitos `<datalist>` ao invés de carregar uma lista de `<option>` dentro do `<datalist>`.

Sugiro dar uma boa revisada no código, e pra trabalhar com ajax comece a  utilizar o "console" do navegador para identificar os erros de forma mais rápida.

Comment: Estarei revisando o código e farei as correções sugeridas